# Nucleophilic comparison of epoxides and ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, ethers

> [image]

Why does $\ce{H+}$ attack on epoxide and not on the double bonded oxygen?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that H+ does protonate the carbonyl group in equilibrium with the protonated epoxide. However this is of no consequence because the protonated carbonyl form is a dead end, all it can do it swap with the protonated epoxide; whereas the protonated epoxide has this forward route open to it.